# Removing menu delays in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to remove all menu delay in Eclipse? By menu delay I mean the delay for opening submenus when the mouse hovers over a folder item.

Comment: Is the delay inconsistent with other apps on your operating system? Eclipse using native controls, so OS rather than Eclipse is in control of the delay.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik It seems to be indeed consistent  with other apps (although it's hard to see precisely since menu delays are typically a few hundreds of milliseconds). Sorry I didn't know that Eclipse uses native controls, I guess you can post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses native controls, so OS rather than Eclipse is in control of menu cascade delay.

Answer (score 0):

As Konstantin Komissarchik pointed out in his answer, the OS settings need to be changed.

For Windows (tested with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate), removing menu delays can be done as follows:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Write in the input box `REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\desktop" -v MenuShowDelay -d 0 -t REG_SZ -f`
3. Press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Alternatively, one can create a .reg file (e.g. `fixmenu.reg`) with the following content, and execute it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\desktop]
"MenuShowDelay"="0"
```

As usual, for the change to be effective restart the Windows session (by log off/in, or rebooting the OS).

---

On Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 there doesn't seem to be any delay (please leave a comment or edit my answer if that's incorrect).